# Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i 【what is " i " !?!?】react navigation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react native 0.61.5 version.

What is "i"?

[image: Hello " i "]
I looked for "i" in my project.
But, as far as I can tell, I couldn't find any mistakes.

I commented out App.tsx.
Then commented out the following part and the error disappeared. The same error occurs even if you remove the comment out of the same description.

```
// const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
//   return (
//     <HomeStack.Navigator>
//       <HomeStack.Screen
//         name="Home"
//         component={Home}
//         options={{
//           headerLeft: () => HeaderDrawer(navigation),
//         }}
//       />
//     </HomeStack.Navigator>
//   );
// };
```

From this, I realized that react navigation v5 was bad.

Someone please give me information
If you are in the same situation, we will ask for information.

Comment: probably a variable from minified code.

Comment: @Sulthan 
Here's how to find it.
I use github. But I did commit, is there a way to go back using git until the error goes away?

Comment: Checkout previous commit? Or the one before?

Comment: @Sulthan
I tried to return the commit with git, but nothing changed ....

Answer (score 1):

I have won. I am crying.
At last I found "i".
It's my victory of seeing the code for four days.
The error was right.
I grew up again as a person

[image]